# Backspace, delete, space etc. dont't work in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with visual Studio, i don't want use it but i have to.

The keys like delete, space etc. don't work and look at menu bar-> duplicated(few times) menu elements.

[image]

Comment: do they work outside visual c++?

Comment: Your studio configuration appears to be broken, maybe the shortcut-configuration is getting in your way... :/

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut-configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Visual Studio gets wonky and you ***don't have a lot of settings you're afraid of losing***, a simple way (provided you can still open the menus) to fix it is usually to go to

```
Tools -> Import and Export Settings
```

and choose `Reset all Settings`. That should fix whatever configuration is broken. Of course that won't necessarily fix it if it's actual code in a plugin that makes things not work.

If you can't even get to the menus, exit Visual Studio and (from a Visual Studio command prompt) run;

```
Devenv /ResetSettings
```

...and that should give the same effect.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. I am going to teach a guy some algorithms and he wanted to use POS Visual Studio (doesn't understand that it is overkill for that kind of things.)
With every turrning on of Visual Studio I get more menu elements.

Comment: @RobertKilar Well, unfortunately then all I got is trying `devenv /setup` which will force Visual Studio to re-merge all menus from all VSPackages. May fix menu related problems, but shouldn't be related to your keyboard problems.

Comment: I wanted to use that but unfortunately command prompt says it doesn't know that command.

Comment: @RobertKilar Odd, mine does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ex6a2fad(v=vs.100) Could be missing in Express.

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been marked as answered, but the fix for me, every time this happens, is to simple press Ctrl+Tab while in Visual Studio.  Some have stated that just changing tabs in VS will also fix it.  Give that a try.

Note that I've never seen the menu duplication, but it does fix the keyboard not responding for several important keys like backspace, delete, arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Caps lock 'on' in VS 2022 won't let you use del, delete, backspace.

Caps lock 'off' should be your first try. :)

Answer (score -1):

Restarting VS worked for me.

I attempted to reset the settings but that didn't work in my case. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.